Meshing a parametrized surface
I have a problem which I thought was standard, but it appears not to be.
I have a closed surface in 3D space (the membrane of a red blood cell). The surface is parametrized using spherical harmonics.
The initial shape of the cell is roughly a sphere. Thus, a regular mesh in parameter (theta, phi) space leads to a nice and regular mesh in real (X, Y, Z) space. As simulation time advances, the cell deforms and eventually the original theta-phi mesh leads to highly distorted triangles in X, Y, Z space.
The question is this: how can I optimize the mesh in parameter (theta-phi) space so as to get a good mesh in real (X, Y, Z) space?
Thanks for any help!
Stephan
